# Optimization with probability densities - Lagrange multipliers

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

This question is concerned with the paper ["A Lower Bound for a Probability Moment of any Absolutely Continuous Distribution with Finite Variance"](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177729447) by Sigeiti Moriguti appeared in Ann. Math. Statist. Volume 23, Number 2 (1952), 286-289.

In this paper the author has considered the following constrained optimization problem.

Consider all probability densities  $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with respect the Lebesgue measure satisfying $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2 f(x) dx = \sigma^2.$$ We need to find the probability density minimizing $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)^{\alpha} dx,$$
 where $\alpha >1.$

Lagrangian associated with this problem is 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)^{\alpha} dx - \lambda \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2 f(x) dx - \mu \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$$
Then we obtain the characteristic equation
$$\alpha \, f(x)^{\alpha-1} - \lambda x^2 - \mu = 0 .$$

From this we obtain
\begin{equation}
\label{}
f(x) = \left[\frac{\lambda x^2 + \mu}{\alpha}\right]^{\frac{1}{\alpha-1}} \, \, \, \,  ---\, \, (1)
\end{equation}

Then he claims the following.

> We should take $\lambda$ negative, and consquently $\mu$ is positive. Then the solution (1) is applicable in the interval $(-\sqrt{-\mu /\lambda}, \sqrt{-\mu /\lambda})$. Outside of this interval, $f(x)$ should be identically taken to be $0$.

My questions are the following.

1. How is he able to claim that $\lambda$ should be negative?
2. Outside of the mentioned interval $f(x)$ should be $0$ implies the following. $f(x) = 0$ implies $\lambda x^2 + \mu \le 0.$ Why should this be the case?

Can someone give a rigorous argument for these claims?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda$ isn't negative, then for large $x$ we have $f(x)\sim x^r$ with $r=\frac{\alpha-1}{2}> 0$. So $f(x)$ doesn't vanish at infinity and as such the PDF cannot be normalized to have total probability $1$.

If $\lambda$ is negative, then $f(x)$ vanishes when $x^2=-\lambda/\mu$. Since probability densities must be nonnegative, the definition of $f(x)$ assumed initially can only be valid for $x$ such that $|x| \leq \sqrt{\lambda/\mu}$. The simplest solution is to just cut off the PDF here, which is the route they take.

Comment: There is likely a more rigorous argument for $f(x)$ taken to remain zero for $|x|\geq \sqrt{-\lambda/\mu}.$ I'll see if I can add that later.

Comment: Thank you for the interest shown in this. See if you can give a rigorous argument.